# Infragistics XamDataGrid - How to style HeaderLabelArea seperators

Tags: c#, infragistics, xamdatagrid

My development environment is C#. I am trying to either change the colors or remove the separators in an Infragistics XamDataGrid header as shown in the image below.

[image: header]

The column 'Name' between Mapping and Price Name is edited using Snoop, therefore it is not white anymore.

Comment: Have a read of http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/62849.aspx

Comment: It looks like what I am after to achieve does not get affected by the LabelPresenter. I've tried setting every properties that I can find in either `HeaderPresenter` and `HeaderLabelArea`, but I'm unsuccessfull in removing those white bars...

Answer (score 0):

xamGrid.FixedRowSeparatorStyle should be the property you are looking for...

Have a look at [this designers style guid for some helpful pointers](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/Designers_Guide_Styling_Points_for_xamGrid.html)

EDIT: Doh!, well spotted alhalama, my bad... hopefully this should help... taken from: [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/39646.aspx)

"The gap could be caused by margings/paddings inside the control template. For example on the main Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="labelCntr" Margin="2,4,2,4" Background="#00000000">
```

Another thing you could do is set the background of the header record to the same color as the label presenters so that the gap will have the same color. You can do that with a style for the DataRecordPresenter and creating a trigger for the RecordType property"

Comment: Infragistics has two WPF data grid controls.  The XamGrid and the XamDataGrid.  Being that this question is for the XamDataGrid this answer isn't likely to help.